# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_user1_user_id'

Tags: python, django

I got an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_user1_user_id'`. I wrote in tests.py

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.test import TestCase
from app.models import Companytransaction
import xlrd

# Create your tests here.
class CompanytransactionModelTests(TestCase):
    def __init__(self, sheet_path):
        self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(sheet_path)
        self.sheet = self.book.sheet_by_index(1)

    def setUp(self):
        self.book = xlrd.open_workbook('./data/excel1.xlsx')
        self.sheet = self.book.sheet_by_index(1)
        num = 0
        for row_index in range(2,4):
            row = self.sheet.row_values(row_index)
                user = Companytransaction(user_id=row[1], name=row[2], age=row[3])
                user.save()

                if num == 0:
                    self.user1 = Companytransaction.objects.create(user_id=row[1], name=row[2], age=row[3])
                    num += 1
                elif num == 1:
                    self.user2 = Companytransaction.objects.create(user_id=row[1], name=row[2], age=row[3])
                    num += 1
                else:
                    self.user3 = Companytransaction.objects.create(user_id=row[1], name=row[2], age=row[3])

    def test_user1_company_id(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.user1.user_id, '100')

    def test_user1_corporation_id(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.user1.name, 'Tom')

    def test_user1_company_name(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.user1.age, '29')
```

I run `python manage.py test` & `./manage.py test app.tests`, but both of them shows the same error. I surely made `user_id column` in `models.py`, so I really cannot understand why this error happens. How can I fix this?
 What should I write this?

Here's the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 29, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 62, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 600, in run_tests
    suite = self.build_suite(test_labels, extra_tests)
  File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 484, in build_suite
    tests = self.test_loader.loadTestsFromName(label)
  File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 190, in loadTestsFromName
    return self.loadTestsFromModule(obj)
  File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 123, in loadTestsFromModule
    tests.append(self.loadTestsFromTestCase(obj))
  File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 92, in loadTestsFromTestCase
    loaded_suite = self.suiteClass(map(testCaseClass, testCaseNames))
  File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/unittest/suite.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.addTests(tests)
  File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/unittest/suite.py", line 57, in addTests
    for test in tests:
  File "/Users/xxx/app/app/tests.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(sheet_path)
  File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 116, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_user1_user_id'
```

Comment: May you please add in the whole traceback? That will help us a lot in figuring out a solution for your problem.

Comment: It's complaining about a missing _file_, not a missing database column.  How is your database defined?  Are you using sqlite3?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais I added traceback to my question.If u know something please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with your `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, sheet_path):
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(sheet_path)
    self.sheet = self.book.sheet_by_index(1)
```

You're getting this error because you aren't providing `sheet_path` when `CompanytransactionModelTests` is initialized. We can see from the [unittest.TestCase source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/unittest/case.py#L388) that `modelName` is the first & only argument when initializing a `TestCase`. I'd bet a penny that you've got a method called `test_user1_user_id` on a class with similar `__init__` code.

Setting up that test data in `setUp` is the right way to do what you're doing. It looks like things should work properly if you get rid of that `__init__` code.